# How to create a newsletter application?

Tags: php, newsletter

I'm required to create a newsletter php application that would send template emails to all subscribed to the system users. 
We're currently using PostgreSQL so PhpList will not work for us if it's not capable to work with PostgreSQL.

What's the appropriate way of handling this task ? Also keep in mind that there will be big amounts of subscribers.

Edit: I'm opened to java applications that could do the trick..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newsletter+php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mailing-list+php ?

Comment: @ax yes I kind of did it. most of the apps I saw were for mysql ?

Comment: Check out this site [www.thetutlage.com](http://www.thetutlage.com), they have video tutorials and are really helpful. I believe it's the best tutorial I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a custom newsletter daemon you can use System::Daemon.
Try using this example for daemons: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Beware:
If you make daemons that will run infinitive you should be aware that php caches things in the ram. So if you're not careful you'll end up with no ram :)

Answer (score 1):

Get Mailman:

http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html

Then send your newsletter to mailman (that's just one adress) and allow mailman to distribute the Newsletter to thousands of recipients (that you configure in Mailman). Of course there is other software besides Mailman, that can do just that...

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is concentrating in sending out emails as such there's no login area covered, but it's recommended you should have your script to send emails stored somewhere secure so only people who should be able to access it can do.

Lets start with the form, all we need is a field for the subject and a field for the message, you can put HTML into the message as we will filter it out for the text email later